# How can I select features for a symbolic regression problem to be solved with genetic programming?

Tags: genetic-algorithms, feature-selection, genetic-programming, algorithm-request

I want to solve a symbolic regression problem with genetic programming. My dataset is similar to [this one](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_boston.html), but I have 30 features, and I want to use only the most sensitive features. I found [this library](https://gplearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#symbolic-regressor) interesting for Symbolic Regression, but could not find the right approach for feature selection.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the existing feature selection techniques typically used in machine learning? If yes, why aren't they good for you? If not, it may be a good idea to have a look at them. Once you know the answer to your question, feel free to write it below (if it's good ehough) ;)

Comment: You should probably read this: [Feature Selection to Improve Generalization of
Genetic Programming for High-Dimensional Symbolic Regression](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7879832).

Comment: I do not have full access to that paper, but it claims as follows, In this paper, we propose a new feature selection method based on permutation to select features for high-dimensional SR using GP. So, `permutation using GP`. what's it really?

Comment: You can find a freely available version of this paper (or a draft) on the web.

Comment: Is there a python library for GP?

Comment: Yes, you can use DEAP. Anyway, if you find an answer to your own question, feel free to write it below, with some details and maybe a link to the references that you used.